# Proving Gabbay rule for Modal Logic

Tags: modal-logic, kripke-models

I'm currently working on exercises of the book "Modal Logic" by A.Chagrov and M.Zakharyaschev (for pleasure, not homework).

One exercise asks to prove this version of Gabbay rule (exercise $3.10$):
A frame $F$ validates the rule $(\Box p \rightarrow p) \vee \psi$ $/$ $\psi$, with $p$ not appearing in $\psi$, if and only if $F$ is irreflexive.

(*Note that: "$p$ not appearing in $\psi$"*).

I have the $\leftarrow$ part, but I'm having a hard time proving the
other implication.
I would really like to understand this excercise, and I know that the
excercises in this book are sometimes hard. But I think this has to be fairly easy.

Until now I tried proving it by reductio ad absurdum: I have one reflexive node $x$, and I try to find a formula $\phi$ that $x$ doesn't validate, but that every other node does validate. If I can prove such formula exists then I'm done, because I plug it in the rule.

I hope I was clear,
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the book, but it looks like a formula $ ConditionQ \to ( (B \lor A))  \to A) $ you are trying to find what $ConditionQ$ is

$ConditionQ$ is just that $ ( (B \lor A))  \to A) $ is a theorem, this means that $B $ has to be false, in this case B is the T axiom (valid in all reflexive frames) so the condition Q is that all frames are irreflexive.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you're looking for is $(\Box p \wedge p)$.

Given formulas $\Box p$, $p$, and $A$, there are 8 ways to construct a world, but only 6 of these worlds are reflexive ($R?$).

```
[]p   p      A      R?
---   ---    ---    ---
F     F      F      T
F     F      T      T
F     T      F      T
F     T      T      T
T     F      F      F
T     F      T      F   <- world x
T     T      F      T
T     T      T      T
```

The only way for $(\Box p \rightarrow p) \vee \psi / \psi$ to be a valid inference rule is for $A$ to be true and $(\Box p \rightarrow p)$ to be false. You can see from this table that this is only true for the row indicated `world x`.

For a world to be reflexive, it must be accessible from itself. Accessibility is determined primarily by the definition of $\Box$. The formula $\Box p(w_0)$ indicates that $p$ is necessarily true in all possible worlds that are *accessible* from world $w_0$, but it is not necessary for $p$ to be true in $w_0$ itself.

If we want to ensure that every world is accessible from itself, we need to impose the restriction that *if* $\Box p(w)$ is true, then $p(w)$ must also be true.

That is precisely what the logical connective $p \rightarrow q$ ("p implies q") means. The truth table looks like this:

```
p     q      p -> q
---   ---    ------
F     F      T
F     T      T
T     F      F
T     T      T
```

Therefore, to ensure reflexivity, we add the axiom $\forall w.\Box p(w) \rightarrow p(w)$, or simply $\Box p \rightarrow p$, and that is why this is called the reflexive axiom.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are missing the "$p$ not appearing in $\psi$" part.

Comment: Well, it's implied by the first truth table. For example, if $A = p$, then world x contains a contradiction, because $p$ is true and $A$ is false, so that line would have to be removed from the list (along with all the other lines where $A$ and $p$ don't match). The only way you get all 8 possible combinations of 3 boolean variables is to make the variables completely independent.

Comment: I don't get how this solves the problem. You say that the formula I'm looking for is $(\Box p \wedge p)$ but $p$ does appear in that formula. And I can't substitue it for, say, $q$ because then we don't get the desired result.

Comment: Perhaps I was wrong about $(\Box p \wedge p)$: I don't really understand the nature of the proof you're trying to write. I don't know what "the $\leftarrow $ part" means or "the other part". All I know is that the only possible way for the statement $(\Box p\rightarrow p) \vee A / A$ to be valid is if $A$ is a theorem and $(\Box p\rightarrow p)$ is an antitheorem. I then showed (by the first truth table) that this is only possible in one situation (world x), and that a frame containing world x cannot be reflexive because $(\Box p\rightarrow p)$ is a necessary condition for reflexivity.