# Reflexive Frame in Temporal Logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I have a question as follows:

A temporal frame $(T,\prec)$ is reflexive if $\prec$ is reflexive.

Write down a temporal formula that is valid on all reflexive frames, but invalid on any other frames.

Should my answer be in this form of

a) $∀x(x\prec)$ or

b) $(GPx\rightarrow x)$ or $(HFx\rightarrow x)$?

Comment: Since you are asked to write down a temporal formula, you should provide a formula of Temporal Logic. So, something like b), but b) is not quite right.

Comment: @CharlesBronson Oh crap is it not? Could you please explain how it's mistaken / how I can get to the right answer?

Comment: @coderperz depending on your model, $G\varphi \to \varphi$ should be enough to force reflexivity

Comment: @CharlesBronson, wouldn't that translate to meaning that at all times in the future when p is True, then p is True, but shouldn't the reflexive frame deal with the present instance of time itself?

My reasoning for GPx->x is that "GP" points back to the current instance of time (as GP, to my understanding, means that for all times in the future there exists a time in the past, which is equivalent to the current time) and so if x holds at the current instance of time then x should be true.

Comment: @coderperz yes, $G\varphi$ is true iff it is true now and at all time points in the future

Comment: @coderperz or think about its dual: $\varphi \to \mathsf{F}\varphi$. If formula $\varphi$ is true now, at the current state, then there is an arrow to a $\varphi$-state

Answer (score 0):

For temporal logic, there are two main characterisations of time: *Instant-based* and *interval-based*.

In instant-based characterisation, the domain of discourse is a set of time instants (points in time) $T$ and a binary relation of temporal precedence $\prec$ on them. Hence a temporal frame can be represented as:

$$\mathcal{T}=\langle T,\prec\rangle$$

In interval-based characterisation, the domain of discourse is a set of time intervals. A typical structure contains the relations of temporal precedence $\prec$, inclusion $\sqsubseteq$, overlap $O$ on a set of time intervals $T$. Thus, the temporal frame can be represented as:

$$\mathcal{T}=\langle T,\prec,\sqsubseteq, O⟩$$

The standard semantics for the minimal temporal logic $\mathbf{K}_{t}$ is Kripke-style instant-based, interpreting possible worlds as time instants, and the accessibility relation as temporal precedence.

If the precedence relation is defined reflexive, then the sentence $\forall x(x\prec x)$ expresses the first-order property of the model over which the $\mathbf{K}_{t}$- formulas are evaluated. In case that the precedence relation is defined irreflexive, then $\forall x\neg(x\prec x)$ holds. Notice that these sentences are *not* in the language of $\mathbf{K}_{t}$.

By basic modal logic, we know that, for a proposition $p$, $\Box p\rightarrow p$ holds if and only if the accessibility relation is reflexive. Analogously, using the strong temporal operators $\mathrm{G}$ or $\mathrm{H}$, we can state that for a model $\mathfrak{T}$ of a reflexive frame

$$\forall x(x\prec x)\iff\mathfrak{T}\vDash Gp\rightarrow p$$
or
$$\forall x(x\prec x)\iff\mathfrak{T}\vDash Hp\rightarrow p$$

Alternatively, using their weak duals

$$\forall x(x\prec x)\iff\mathfrak{T}\vDash p\rightarrow Fp$$
or
$$\forall x(x\prec x)\iff\mathfrak{T}\vDash p\rightarrow Pp$$

for the class of reflexive frames. $ Gp\rightarrow p$ and the others on the right-hand side are the formulas sought for in the language of $\mathbf{K}_{t}$.

As a side note, a more challenging question would be to write a formula valid only on irreflexive frames. For, it is known by Lemmon’s completeness proof for $\mathbf{K}_{t}$ that any consistent set of $\mathbf{K}_{t}$-formulas is satisfiable in a model of an irreflexive frame. A method to circumvent this difficulty is to add a derived rule called [Gabbay rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/687564/754923):

$$\mathrm{H}p\wedge\neg p, \phi\vdash\phi$$ where $p$ is an atomic proposition that does not occur in $\phi$ (*mutatis mutandis* for the other temporal operators).

Comment: What are some axiom schemes for $\sqsubseteq$ and $O$?

Comment: See Goranko and Rumberg's SEoP article [Temporal Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-temporal/) for a handy open source of reference.